# Is toshset still supported?

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I'm trying to install toshset ($ sudo apt-get install toshset) but get this error message below.  Is it still being supported?  How do I install it on to my laptop?

Thanks,
Andy

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package toshset is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'toshset' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

That is only available for [xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=toshset) so either they stopped providing a debian installer or forgot to update their version.  From the [website](http://www.schwieters.org/toshset/) you can download a tar or binary.

Comment: tested now and it doesn't work on bionic